# MATLAB camera adapter error

Tags: matlab, adapter

my problem is that error when I'm trying to use laptop cam in Matlab
the code

```
testimg = videoinput('dcam');
```

I get that error

```
Error using videoinput (line 233)
There are no devices installed for the specified ADAPTORNAME. See IMAQHWINFO.

Error in CameraTest (line 1)
testimg = videoinput('dcam');
```

although when I use imaqhwinfo method I get that the installed adapter is 'dcam'

```
>> imaqhwinfo

ans = 

    InstalledAdaptors: {'dcam'}
        MATLABVersion: '8.3 (R2014a)'
          ToolboxName: 'Image Acquisition Toolbox'
       ToolboxVersion: '4.7 (R2014a)'
```

so where is the problem ?

Comment: What is returned from `imaqhwinfo('dcam')`?

Comment: @nkjt
>> imaqhwinfo('dcam')

ans = 

       AdaptorDllName: 'C:\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R2014a\dcam\adaptor\win64\mwdcamimaq.dll'
    AdaptorDllVersion: '4.7 (R2014a)'
          AdaptorName: 'dcam'
            DeviceIDs: {1x0 cell}
           DeviceInfo: [1x0 struct]

Comment: The fact that the Device IDs cell array is empty means that you can't instantiate and instance of your camera.  This means that your computer doesn't recognize the camera, even though `dcam` is recognized in MATLAB: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/168913-trouble-with-videoinput-and-dcam-device - Try to reinstall the drivers for your webcam.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks but I've done that more than once and the same error still here

Comment: @Hoby - I'm out of ideas. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found it!

write this in the command window

```
supportPackageInstaller
```

and select install from Internet, then select from that package from list 'OS Generic Video Interface'
and 'winvideo' adapter will work successfully !!